# Edit a text file over FTP in C#?

Tags: c#, ftp, streamreader, streamwriter

I want to, basically, use the following code to edit a C# file:

```
var file = new StreamReader("ftp://xxx.xxx.x.x/xxx.txt"); //[ip address/file]
        label1.Text = file.ReadLine();
        file.Close();
        var fw = new StreamWriter("ftp://xxx.xxx.x.x/xxx.txt"); //[ip address/file]
        fw.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
        fw.Close();
```

But it doesn't work, how do I do this?

Comment: I think you need to look up the FTP protocol, there's a lot more too this than opening and closing like a local file. You could make a library that makes it that easy, but it's not natively so.

Comment: *Doesn't work* is a problem description which is often used by people who doesn't know/care how computers work and is totally inappropriate for software developers. Software developers (especially those asking questions on StackOverflow) usually express what are they trying to achieve, the expected result, what they have tried in order to achieve it, the obtained result and the way it differs from the expected result. So what happens when you run this code? You get an exception? A BSOD? Your computer crashes? Apples start falling from the sky?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov i really think that "Doesn't work is a problem description which is often used by people who doesn't know/care" about people that might want to help solving the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit file via FTP is:

1. Download file
2. Edit file locally (in memory)
3. Upload file

For steps 1 and 3 check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx).

Comment: Thnx! I ended up using: var x = new WebClient();
            x.BaseAddress = "ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.x/xxx.txt";
            x.DownloadFile(x.BaseAddress, "wazadoin.txt");
            var xyz = new StreamReader("wazadoin.txt");
            label1.Text = xyz.ReadLine();

Comment: @IMAPC this is basically the same steps, just another class.

Comment: You can even shell an editor at step2, and add a FileSystemWatcher to watch when the user actually save the file and automatically push on the server ( or optionally asking the user ).

Answer (score 2):

The FtpWebRequest seems very complex compared to the ftplib library @ http://ftplib.codeplex.com/

Here is their example...

```
   using (FtpConnection ftp = new FtpConnection("ftpserver", "username", "password"))
   {

   ftp.Open(); /* Open the FTP connection */
   ftp.Login(); /* Login using previously provided credentials */

   if (ftp.DirectoryExists("/incoming")) /* check that a directory exists */
       ftp.SetCurrentDirectory("/incoming"); /* change current directory */

   if (ftp.FileExists("/incoming/file.txt"))  /* check that a file exists */
       ftp.GetFile("/incoming/file.txt", false); /* download /incoming/file.txt as file.txt to current executing directory, overwrite if it exists */

   //do some processing

   try
   {
       ftp.SetCurrentDirectory("/outgoing");
       ftp.PutFile(@"c:\localfile.txt", "file.txt"); /* upload c:\localfile.txt to the current ftp directory as file.txt */
   }
   catch (FtpException e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(String.Format("FTP Error: {0} {1}", e.ErrorCode, e.Message));
   }

   foreach(var dir in ftp.GetDirectories("/incoming/processed"))
   {
       Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
       Console.WriteLine(dir.CreationTime);
       foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
       {
           Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
           Console.WriteLine(file.LastAccessTime);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) class that is included in .NET 4.0 to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

As i see i`m a little late, but i faced the same problem like you, and after i dig for a solution, i found a way to do the changes without downloading, and uploading the file.

My goal was to save all the changes made during the program execution at the closing, and to load these data at program start from a .txt file stored in a FTP server.

Here is the two methods are used:

```
public static void Save(ArrayList dataStore)
    {
        WebClient request = new WebClient();
        string url = "ftp://ftpname/directory/" + "file.txt";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        Stream postStream = request.OpenWrite(url);

        foreach (Data data in dataStore)
        {
            byte[] writeData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data + "#");
            postStream.Write(writeData, 0, writeData.Length);
        }
    }

public static ArrayList Load()
    {
        ArrayList dataStore = new ArrayList();

        WebClient request = new WebClient();
        string url = "ftp://ftpname/directory/" + "file.txt";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

        byte[] newFileData = request.DownloadData(url);
        string fileString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newFileData);

        if (fileString == "")
        {
            return dataStore;
        }

        string[] dataString = fileString.Split('#');

        foreach (string data in dataString)
        {
            if (data != "")
            {
                dataStore.Add(data);
            }
        }

        return dataStore;
    }
```